# Restrict Download of files from Google Drive per day basis in Android app

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api, download

I want to create an Android App with Google Drive API. Here User will authenticate with Google accounts and have access to list of files in the particular folder of my Google drive. From the list of files user can download any one.

Now I want to restrict the downloading per user to a certain no of files on per day basis. Is it possible to to do the same using Google API for Android?

Is there is anyway I can restrict Download of files from my Google Drive to user on per day basis in my new Android app?

Comment: How important is it to protect against user tampering?  Is it a problem if an attacker figures out how to exceed the restriction?

Comment: May be there would be solution for that as well

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Do you mean that is important or it isn't?

Comment: AFAIK there is no official error handling or limit downloading of files based on the [Handling API Errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors) document. I think you can create your own implementation about this restriction.